# UIActivityTypePrint causes UIActivityViewController not to show

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I try to share some documents I get following error:

2017-12-12 17:12:47.466089+0100 MyApp[415:77472] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

2017-12-12 17:12:52.284992+0100 MyApp[415:77472] [ShareSheet] ERROR:  timed out waiting to establish a connection to the ShareUI view service extension.

Code that does not work:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:documents applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = barButtonItem;
[viewController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If I add following line, everything seems to be working normally

```
 activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint];
```

Current min sdk version is 10.0

Is there something that I'm missing? Do we need additional permissions for that? Added same functionality to another app(min sdk is 9.0) and it seems to be working properly?

Comment: FYI: you will probably find your workaround (excluding printing) does not work reliably, esp. on a variety of OS versions devices.